# md5 variable assigns same value

Tags: typescript, ionic3, md5

I am wanting to create md5 variable and use that to hash unique form values and sending to an API for unique data, however every time I submit the data the md5 value is the same.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Platform  } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ModalController, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Md5 } from 'ts-md5/dist/md5';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
selector: 'page-bol',
templateUrl: 'bol.html',
})
export class BolPage {

private chemInfo:any[] = [];
private submitAllData:any[] = [];
private lonlat:any = [];
private md5Data:any;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
          public navParams: NavParams,
          public modalCtrl: ModalController,
          private geolocation: Geolocation
          private platform: Platform) {
  }

ionViewDidLoad() {

   /* Ensure the platform is ready */
   this.platform.ready().then(() => {
   /* Perform initial geolocation */
   this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
       this.lonlat = [resp.coords.latitude,resp.coords.longitude];
       console.log(this.lonlat);
     }).catch((error) => {
       console.log('Error getting location', error);
     });
   });
}

submitBOL(form: NgForm){
   //console.log(form.value);
   var md5 = new Md5();
   this.submitAllData.push(form.value,{'sub':this.chemInfo}, 
  {'gpsLoc':this.lonlat.toString()});

   //In theory this value should be unique every time
   this.md5Data = md5.appendStr(form.value.toString()).appendStr(this.chemInfo.toString()).appendStr(this.lonlat.toString()).end();
   this.submitAllData.push({'md5':this.md5Data});
   console.log(this.submitAllData);
}
```

I keep getting this value from the console:
{"md5":"703137aef9805f0ca95b8c8b56619f84"} and I'm not sure why it is the same value every time.  I'm not very familiar with this functionality in Ionic so any feedback helps. Thanks!

Comment: so did you try to console.log(form.value.toString(),this.chemInfo.toString(), this.lonlat.toString()) just before md5 hashing and ensure these are actually different strings?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure there was an issue with the local environment because it worked fine on a device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found my answer. Apparently something on my local machine was causing the hash print out the same md5 string, but I went ahead and tested it on my android device and it worked fine! 
I know for a fact it is very rare the data will be the same let alone the gps location. So I tested multiple times on the device and it gave me a unique hash every time!

edit: I also changed the code up a bit and this seemed to be the issue.

```
  (JSON.stringify(form.value)).appendStr(JSON.stringify(this.chemInfo))
```

I was trying to get the array to string using .toString() instead of JSON.stringify which was returning an object instead of a string.